# Are questions regarding reference material considered off topic?

Tags: discussion

Title states the issue.  Specifically, I'm looking for a bit of material on a topic of computer science and practical application of the principle.

I'm not looking for code, but I am interested in how the "science" applies to a specific application, and how the application can be enhanced through the science of the topic.

Is this considered on topic?

Comment: too vague! be specific! in general it sounds ok. note [chat] is a good place to get advice, mods & other users hang out

Comment: Can you give us more details about the question you want to ask, and what research you have done?  Reference requests can easily end up being too broad.  Also, this site does not work well for "give me a list of X" questions.  It's important that it be possible to select a single, correct answer, using some objectively-evaluable criteria that are stated in the question.  Also, I expect people to do a significant amount of research on their own before asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too vague to answer definitely. Reference requests are ontopic in principle but we would like them to be reasonable scoped. "Has method X been applied to Y problem Z?" might work out, but "What are all the applications of CS in biology?" is way too broad.

If your question falls into the latter category, try to narrow your query down by using Google Scholar (or similar). That said, you can always try and post your question; the community will then inspect your question and "judge". (I appreciate you asking first, though. [Computer Science Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2710) is a good hint.)